# Why was a correct answer deleted and converted to a comment?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, deleted-answers, specific-answer, convert-to-comment

Please refer to the following question (on SO):

[How to list all the files changed by a perforce change list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387349/how-to-list-all-the-files-changed-by-a-perforce-change-list/)

One of the answers to the question was deleted and converted to a comment:

[image]

Although many [perforce](/questions/tagged/perforce) users might not be aware, this is a **correct answer**.  I would even go on to say that is better than the accepted answer in the thread.

Unfortunately, it was converted to a comment.

---

The reference to the (deleted) answer can be observed in another answer:

[image]

and also in a comment:

[image]

Was it deleted simply due to the fact that `to err is human`?  Was it removed because the reviewers without a *minimal understanding* voted to delete it?

---

EDIT: It is worthwhile to state that this was a **first post** (link to user's [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1404462/user114245)) and a **late answer**.  So it would have *featured* in both the relevant review queues.  Moreover, it might have appeared in the **Low Quality Posts** queue too given it's length.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably because it started with the word Probably.

Comment: Seriously now... answer should be definitive, if it's just a guess... it probably should not be an answer.

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the following two words `probably the easiest`.

Comment: @devnull you are probably right, I guess

Comment: @dev I wasn't the one to delete, just explain the motive. If the answer would have started with "The easiest..." good chances it wouldn't have been converted to comment. Moderators act on flags, and they have LOTS of flags. If they see short answer that appears to be more of a guess than actual answer, they'll push the red button. :)

Comment: Sounds odd to me.  OP _probably_ didn't want to sound too __definitive__ while saying that this was the `easiest way`.

Comment: So this answer is another candidate of comment :)

Comment: That answer did not have much content, the moderator most probably acted in good faith. Elaborating a little more about what the solution does and why it's the easiest would probably have prevented this. Probably.

Comment: @devnull I agree it's a fair answer and shouldn't have been deleted. However it's not relevant now with [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17225647/447356)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Doesn't it imply that we tend to flag posts without _a minimal understanding_?

Comment: @devnull, depends, most of the time content problems can be addressed without full expertise on the topic. In addition, one or more flags might have prompted the moderator to delete the answer.

Comment: Nevertheless, this reminds me of another question: [Shouldn't reviews be done a bit more carefully?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201617/shouldnt-reviews-be-done-a-bit-more-carefully)

Comment: @devnull not relevant, most likely (oops... meant probably ;)) it wasn't part of review just a user who stumbled over that answer and decided to flag.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd _Probably_.  However, it's worthwhile to note that it was a _late answer_ __and__ a _first post_.

Comment: @devnull but it was deleted five months after being posted so unlikely it was flagged as part of review.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I don't have _data_ to conclude anything.  However, chances are that it'd have been flagged during review.  Might have _eventually_ achieved a certain number of flags for the mods to act.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It's also _possible_ that the post turned active when the answer was updated [2 months](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10661072/revisions) later and made it's way to `Low Quality Posts` queue.

Comment: @dev maybe, but like I said, not very likely.

Answer (score 6):

As @ShaWizDowArd said, I'd suspect it's because the entire answer is "Probably the easiest way:" with absolutely no explanation of why that is "probably" the best way.

Code-only answers are discouraged on SO, because they offer no information in addition to the code. SO isn't a "Find me code I can copy/paste" site; it's a collection of information and knowledge, and that answer doesn't impart the knowledge to go with the code.

It's fine to think something is "probably the best way", but the answer also needs to explain **why** that's the case, and provide enough information to do so. I'd have flagged that as "Other", with a reason that it's a comment and not an answer as well.

Comment: I agree that code-only answers might be off-topic. However, when a command is all that's required to answer the question, I'm not sure if an elaborate explanation is needed.

Comment: @devnull: I didn't say "elaborate". :-) Some explanation other than "Probably the best way" is in order, though. Even if it's a command that's needed, an explanation of what the command does and a link to the documentation is helpful, especially to new coders (which are IMO the majority of question posters on SO). If the "answer" isn't worthy of that much effort, it's a comment. :-)

Comment: Your answer would _discourage_ me from posting an answer from my mobile.  If I'm posting using mobile, its inevitable that I won't include links to RTFM (read the fantastic manual).

Comment: @devnull: Sorry, but posting from a mobile device doesn't alleviate the need to post a decent answer. If you can't do that, leave a comment instead. As I said, "Probably the best way" is not an answer, regardless of how you're accessing the site. You still need to provide a sufficient answer.